# How to filter columns by its content pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with boolean columns. I want to filter out those which have mostly `True` in it. For example if we have dataframe

```py
    A     B     C
0   True  False True
1   False False True
2   True  True  False
```

Then columns `A` and `C` should be filtered and only column `B` must remain. I've come up with the following solution:

```py
def check_mostly_false(col):
    values, counts = np.unique(df[col], return_counts=True)
    if values[np.argmax(counts)] == False:
         return True
    return False
false_columns = list(filter(check_mostly_false, df.columns))
```

I wonder if there is more elegant and efficient way to do that? Using `pandas` functionality for example.

Comment: What is ouput if 4 rows and 2 times False and 2 times True ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution with count values per columns and first maximal value by [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html), for filter by `False` is use inverse mask by `~`:

```
L = df.columns[~df.apply(pd.value_counts).idxmax()].tolist()
```

Or is possible use `mean` with filter for less like `0.5`:

```
#if same True, False not counts return False columns
L = df.columns[df.mean().lt(0.5)].tolist()

#if same True, False counts return False columns
L = df.columns[df.mean().le(0.5)].tolist()
```

Comment: @NuriTaş - I ask OP what should be ouput if 50-50.